# How do I implement matlab code on hardware device to make it run?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler, matlab-coder, hdl-coder

My question is quite basic to most appropriate levels on consideration. I lack the perception of how can I dump or implement my matlab code on a hardware component like processors or fpga? For eg:
Suppose I create an image processing matlab (object classification/detection) code which needs to detect real time images from drone and identify whether object is human or animal while its one air through the vision of camera, how shall I proceed to implement this matlab code onto a processor or controller and make it run while the drone is on air?
For consideration, take the matlab code is in its raw form for processing any input data and put out an output classified data. What should I do next? Do I need to convert the matlab code to any hdl or .exe format to run it across the hardware platform or is it possible to implement matlab code(.m format) directly into a device for processing and classification. Basically I am not getting how to practically use matlab code and put it into a system. Do I need to use some sort of toolbox or extension code ?
Could you please list down the steps for this process or share some link of website or youtube videos where it has been shown in detail how to harbour this mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You could use MATLAB Coder to convert your MATLAB code to an executable that can run on your hardware.

Here are a couple of articles from the official MathWorks documentation regarding Code Generation for Image Processing to get you started:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/code-generation-for-image-processing.html

https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/code-generation-with-cell-detection.html